# Calculate product price based on multiple percentage factors

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm attempting to throw together a Python script which accepts several variables and outputs a price based on a target profit margin (percentage).

If I come up with a price I can calculate the percentage margin on it. For example, let's say I have a product that I am listing for `$49.00`.

- Item cost: `$14.00`
- Marketplace cost: 10% of $49 (`$4.90`)
- Payment processor cost: 2.9% (`$1.42`)
- Total costs: `$20.32` ($14 + $4.90 + $1.42)
- Total profit: `$28.68` ($49 - $20.32)
- Calculated profit margin: 58.53% ((100 / 49) * 28.68)

However, when attempting to flip the problem and generate a price based on cost, profit margin, marketplace pecentage and payment processor percentage, I'm at a complete loss on how to solve this.

Has anyone else tackled this problem and if so, do you have any pointers or would you provide a solution for me to work from to better understand how to tackle these sorts of challenges in the future?

Examples don't necessarily have to be in Python, that just happens to be the language I'm working in.

---

Huge thanks to `@mtadd` for laying this out in lehman's terms.

Below is a working example of how this was solved in Python:

```
import decimal

item_cost = decimal.Decimal('14.00')
market_multiplier = decimal.Decimal('0.10') # 10% / 100
payment_processor_multiplier = decimal.Decimal('0.029') # 2.9% / 100
profit_margin = decimal.Decimal('0.5853') # 58.53% / 100

price = costs / (
    decimal.Decimal('1') -
    profit_margin -
    market_fees_multiplier -
    payment_fees_multiplier
)
```

Printing `price` outputs `28.68`, which is pretty spot on with our 58.53% target margin.

Comment: This is algebra, not programming.  Write the equations with variables for the concepts, rather than specific dollar amounts.  Now solve for the price; substitute one expression for another until the right side consists of the other variables.

If you post your actual equations, I can help walk you through this.

Comment: The calculation of Total Costs in the question is incorrect, I believe.  Total Costs should be the sum of Item, Marketplace, and Payment Processor costs, and not the Price minus those terms.

Comment: @mtadd, you're absolutely right, I flipped the values. Fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the basic algebra.  First, define your symbols:

```
P = Price
MktFrac = Marketplace Fraction
PayFrac = Payment Processor Fraction
C = Cost
TC = Total Cost 
TP = Total Profits 
PM = Profit Margin Fraction
```

note that instead of doing percentages (0-100), I'm using fractions (0-1). You can convert a fraction to a percentage by multiplying by 100.

And then your basic formulas

```
TC = C + MktFrac*P + PayFrac*P
TP = P - TC
PM = TP / P
```

With some substitution and simplification

```
TC = P*(MktFrac+PayFrac) + C
TP = P*(1-MktFrac-PayFrac) - C
PM = 1-MktFrac-PayFrac - C/P
```

So that's the formula for Profit Margin with everything on the right hand side.  If you want to solve for Price, first isolate the term with Price by itself:

```
1 - PM - MktFrac - PayFrac = C/P
```

Divide by Cost

```
1/P = (1 - PM - MktFrac - PayFrac)/C
```

And take reciprocal

```
P = C/(1 - PM - MktFrac - PayFrac)
```

or in percentages:

```
P = C/(1 - PM - MktPct/100 - PayPct/100)
```

Comment: Man, thanks so much for taking the time to lay this out. Algebra isn't by strong point so this was a HUGE help. I've updated my question to include a working example.